# Sitecore search not working in bucket items folder for non-admin roles in Sitecore 10.2

Tags: indexing, cms-only

We are using Sitecore 10.2. We have a user with following roles,
[image]

This user is not able to search bucket items in items folder. The same folder is working as expected for Admin user.

[image]

Are we missing any roles?

Comment: Can you try giving the `developer` role to this user?

Comment: Are you sure the role is the issue? Could also be security on item level..

Comment: @SumitBhatia This user is for Sales team. So we are providing restricted access to them.

Comment: @Gatogordo Security on item looks fine. We are upgrading from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 10.2, same role/user works fine in Sitecore 8.2

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you mean with "not able to search"? What are you trying exactly - where are you searching and how.

Comment: If you think it is a security issue - have you checked the access viewer?

Comment: I have updated the question with the behavior we are facing. For administrator search is returning results.